# Installing Office 365 on Kubuntu Wine

Tags: office365, wine, kubuntu

I am looking forward to installing Office 365 on Kubuntu using Wine. I have the Office 365 ODT exe installer and a configuration xml file. The install on Windows would be simply `odt.exe /configure config.xml`, however the Wine CMD doesn't seem to be willing to accept the argument. I can run `odt.exe` directly without arguments (as in, not outright failing when launched, as opposed to passing in a config xml, not sure if it will run after I check the box to accept the eula), but that installs extra stuff that I don't need. I followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/hhvx17/comment/fwd7bhu) and [this guide](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527) that tells me the steps, but they don't tell me how to pass a config xml file to the installer. I've changed the default Wine prefix to 32 bit, performed the registry edits, and installed the dll overrides. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

---

Update:

I've managed to get the installer from office.com (as the guides called for), but passing a configuration file still fails, albeit with a different way of conveying the same message, that it didn't manage to accept the argument. I also tried using `/customize` on both the ODT.exe installer I got and the installer I got from office.com, both still fail. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not familiar with Kubuntu Wine, but I want to say the command to run ODT is `setup.exe /configure XXX.xml`. Besides, from the references you provide, they seem to download the Office installation file from [office.com](https://office.com/), not via running ODT with configuration file.

Comment: @Emily I cant seem to find "installation file from office.com", it doesn't seem obvious enough for me. As for the ODT, I followed [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-office-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c#OfficePlans=signinorgid) and selected the "Office for business" tab, which is where I got my ODT.exe from, which I then tried to pass a config xmll to.

Comment: Update: I ran `wine setup.exe /configure Configuration.xml` and it showed the following message: `002a:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.` I did `sudo apt install winbind` and now the error is gone, but it still refuses to run.